# How to edit Java BC CMSSignedData PKCS#7?

Tags: bouncycastle, signed, pkcs#7, oid

I have a BouncyCastle `CMSSignedData` object represented as PKCS#7 signed data.

How can I edit the `CMSSignedData` to remove the value (octet string) of contentInfo 
(OID 1.2.840.113549.1.7.1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `CMSSignedDataGenerator.generate()` is using `CMSObjectIdentifiers.signedData [1.2.840.113549.1.7.2]` as `contentType` when constructing a `CMSSignedData` object. You could rewrite `CMSSignedDataGenerator.java` or better craft your own generator class and use a different `ObjectIdentifier`.

The `bcpkix` sources are available at [bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).

Note that `id-signedData` is the official [RFC 5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5.1) content type for signed-data [CMS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652)  objects:

```
id-signedData OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=
{ iso(1) member-body(2) us(840) rsadsi(113549) pkcs(1) pkcs7(7) 2 }
```